# Overriding parent component method in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class extending a custom component which extends another custom component. I want to override `handleReload()` function to add some extra functionality. I don't want to completely change it's behavior. The problem is that I get errors even when the page loads, and it lacks any functionality.

To sum it up a little bit, there are 3 layers of components, parent -> child -> grandchild, `handleReload()` is declared in child.

```
export default class Child extends Parent {

  handleReload() {
    return () => {
      const { name, load } = this.props
      load(name)
    }
  }

  <ReloadButton
    value={'action.reload'}
    onClick={::this.handleReload()}
    privilege={`${metaForm(name)}:Read`}
  />

}
```

Now what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
export class GrandChild extends Child {

  handleReload() {
    super.handleReload()
    // something else here
 }
}
```

Comment: I think your design is a bit "over complicating" things. Inheritance between components, even if totally possible in react, is a really spare case. In the doc they say that in all the usage they did of react so far, they have never had a case when they needed to use inheritance between components.

Comment: Design cannot be changed. Is there any possible way I could override the method?

Comment: given your code, try adding inside the constructor of your `GrandChild` class the following: `this.handleReload = this.handleReload.bind(this);`

Comment: Had already tried it, didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to evaluate something in `handleReload` to tell it whether it's coming from a grandChild or not and then use a `if` statement of some sort to do *this* or *that*.

```
// ----- parent.js
export class ParentContainer extends Component {

    import {GrandChild} from './components/grandchild';

    handleReload = type => {
      if(type === 'grandchild'){
        // something
      } else {
        // something else
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
            <GrandChild onReload={this.handleReload} /> 
      )
    }
  }
```

Example of passing it back in props

```
// /  ----- /components/grandchild.js 
export class GrandChild extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
            <button onClick={this.props.onReload('grandchild')}
      );
    }
 }
```

Comment: This seems a little bit over the top. I cannot alter the code of the parent.

Comment: Well you can not expect a parent function to do something different based on it's child if you do not evaluate something or pass it a separate function built for the the grandchild.

Comment: Then I should find another logic that will give me the functionality I need. Thanks for your help, appreciated.